# Functions are still being called asynchronously. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

My code is supposed to download 5 files exported from our school's database, then run a query based on the first export (there will be queries for the other four files, and there are three schools, so my functions need to be scalable).

I have a function called "download" and another function called "updateSchedule." Both of these functions work separately.

```js
var download = function(file){
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var i = 1;
    var ftpGet = function(){
        var number = i++;
        toString(number);
        filename = file+number+'.csv';
        ftp.get(filename, filename, function(hadErr){
            if (hadErr){
                console.error('There was an error retrieving ' + filename);
            }else{
                console.log(filename + ' downloaded');
                if(i <= 5){
                    ftpGet();
                }else{
                    deferred.resolve();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    ftpGet();  
    return deferred.promise;
}

var updateSchedule = function(school, school_id){
    var deferred = q.defer();
    console.log('');
    connectionpool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        if(err){
            console.error('CONNECTION error: ', err);
        }else{
            connection.query('DELETE FROM schedule WHERE school_id = "'+school_id+'"', function(err, rows){
                if (err) console.error(err);
                var path = './'+school+'_export1.csv';
                var reader = csv.createCsvFileReader(path, {'separator': ',','quote': '"','excape': '"','comment': ''});
                reader.addListener('data',function(data){
                    connection.query('INSERT INTO schedule SET section_id = "'+data[0]+'", student_id = "'+data[1]+'", course_number = "'+data[2]+'", period = "'+data[3]+'", teacher_id = "'+data[4]+'", school_id = "'+school_id+'"', function(err, rows){
                        if (err) console.error(err);
                        deferred.resolve();
                    }); 
                });
            });
            connection.release();
            console.log(school+' schedule updating...');
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

When I call them using promises, however, I get an error saying it can't open the file. What am I doing wrong?

```js
download('lca_export').then(updateSchedule('lca', '517'));
```

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: To start with, make `filename` a local variable, not an implicit global.  Then, remove `toString(number)` since that isn't doing anything or maybe is causing an error and isn't needed anyway as numbers are automatically converted to strings when being added to other strings.

Comment: could separate `ftpGet()` declaration out from `download()` and make `ftpGet(fileName)` only grab and return one file. `download()` would make multiple `ftpGet()` calls and handle info accordingly.

Comment: @jfriend00 I converted number to a string because the filename ends in a number (e.g. 'lca_export1.csv', 'lca_export2.csv'). Since there are going to be exports from other schools, I need to be able to pass in the value of the "file".

Comment: @theoperator Not sure I understand what that would accomplish. The function already downloads all the files when ran on its own. The problem is "updateSchedule" runs before "download."

Comment: First off if `toString()` even exists (it isn't part of standard Javascript), then `toString(number)` would return it's modified value, not assign that to your number variable.  Second, numbers are automatically converted to strings when added to another string - you do not have to do that manually.  See my answer for the main issue in your code.

Comment: @jfriend00 It does exist (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp), but you're right I was using it wrong. I was going pretty fast, so that and the implicit global were more typos than anything. But I didn't know that numbers were converted to stings like that. I'm still getting used to using JS for server-side things, and that used to get me all the time in PHP. Everything is working great now, though. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3630824 - that's the `.toString()` method which exists on all objects in Javascript.  That's not a `toString()` function by itself like your code had.  In any case, it simply isn't needed as the string conversion happens automatically for numbers when adding them to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
download('lca_export').then(updateSchedule('lca', '517'));
```

to this:

```
download('lca_export').then(function() {
    updateSchedule('lca', '517');
});
```

You were calling `updateSchedule()` immediately and passing the result to `.then()` rather than passing a function reference to `.then()` that can be called later.  Thus, `updateSchedule()` was running before `download()` had done its work.  This is a very common mistake.  Just remember that if there are parens after the function name it will execute immediately.  If it's just a function name or an anonymous declaration without parens, then you're passing a function reference.

---

Some other things to cleanup:

1. Add `var` in front of `filename` to make it a local variable rather than an implicit global.
2. Remove the `toString(number)`.  At best it isn't needed at all and isn't doing anything since you aren't assigning the result to anything.  At worst, it's causing an error because there is no function `toString()`.  FYI, numbers are automatically converted to strings when added to a string so you do not need to do that manually.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! Yea I'm definitely using toString() incorrectly... kinda surprised that worked now that I think about it. Anyway thanks again!